# Match bank transactions between Yodlee connections to the same account

Tags: yodlee

In our application, there are occasionally cases where a bank account is disconnected using [removeItem](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_SOAP_API_Reference/removeItem) and subsequently reconnected using [addItemForContentService1](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_SOAP_API_Reference/addItemForContentService1) from the Yodlee SOAP aggregation API.  There is anecdotal evidence to suggest that, until relatively recently (1-2 months ago?), the transaction IDs for bank transactions that had already been retrieved from a prior connection would be identical when the same bank account was reconnected.  However, now it appears that, when a bank account is disconnected and then reconnected in this way, all of the bank transactions are now assigned new transaction IDs, thus breaking any client logic that attempts to match transactions from previous connections to the same bank account.  This can be a serious problem since, for example, it can produce many duplicate transactions for accounts that have already had bank reconciliations performed.

My questions are whether there now exists a reliable mechanism to identify the same bank transactions when disconnecting and reconnecting to the same bank account using removeItem and addItemForContentService1 and, if so, what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call removeItem the account is deleted and also all the data related to that account is deleted. Now when you call addItemForContentService1 a new itemId is created for that account and data is freshly added to the data base considering the account as new. Since there is no mapping to the old data , so you will not get the same transaction IDs for those transactions.

Hence removeItem should only be called if you wish to delete the account and it's data from Yodlee platform.